# INNODB query end

Tags: mysql, mysql5

My table TABLE IS INNODB

query end | REPLACE INTO TABLE (COLUM1,COLUM2,DATE) VALUES (14411,132,'2015-07-01 12:12:33')

Its taking 2 seconds ?
Whats query end ?

Comment: A status: The query has ended, however an IO (flush most likely) action still has to finish.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the system stalls. The most common reason is that the database perfomes some flushing operation.

A worth while article about the subject is [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/04/innodb-flushing-theory-and-solutions/).